# Laravel. The Response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

This is my array.

```
http://pastebin.com/eTrJ2PVB
```

When I return this array like this, I get an error.

```
return \Response::json($response, 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

However, when I remove JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK, I get the response; but the problem is I need numeric values.

What could be done to resolve this?

Comment: Well.. an array is not a numeric.

Comment: @mrun I need the values to be numeric.

Comment: In that case I'd suggest validating the array by yourself and not relying on `json_encode` on that. Its purpose is not to validate.

Comment: But why does JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK give this error?

Comment: Why do you need them to be numeric? How do you use that array?

Comment: my guess is there is something wrong with your array. have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26022390/the-response-content-must-be-a-string-or-object-implementing-tostring-boo?rq=1)

Comment: The function works fine. It is only giving error for this array. Yes, I have seen that question and did all the things that were mentioned in answers.

Comment: i ran the function with the array you posted and I was not able to recreate your error. can you verify that `return \Response::json(['number' => '16'], 200, [], JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);` runs correctly?

Comment: Please share more details, like the code involved and your attempts to resolve the problem. Please do **not** post the code anywhere else

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention what error you are getting, but I can't reproduce any errors either. In fact this code at http://pastebin.com/GJWrCgwN shows your array returned as a perfectly formatted JSON with literal numbers instead of strings - see results at http://pastebin.com/cYDzDGyE.

BTW, you can also use this alternative syntax where you don't need to mess with HTTP response status code or headers, just the JSON encoding options:

```
return response()->json($response)->setEncodingOptions(JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
```

Check it out at `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse`.

Comment: Could you please elaborate more your answer adding a little more description about the solution you provide?

Comment: @abarisone, I elaborated my answer as you suggested. I don't see a real problem in the original question, but wanted to recommend a better solution anyway. Thank you.