# laravel, ajax call from input to controller function 500 error

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

I'm not sure what's happening with this but when my ajax call is made to my php controller method, I'm getting a 500 error and I'm wondering if it's possibly a data type error or just simply syntax.

The value I'm passing from my form input through tha ajax call and into my function is being passed into a url endpoint in my service.php file.

The ajax itself is calling the function successfully but I can't verify the results from my $searchResults  in the function because it seems to fail at the point of passing.

I started typing Test into my input with a breakpoint in the browser and it showed the value for my input as "T". Should I need to strip quotes or anything like that if it's being used in the query of the endpoint?

What else does it look like I could be doing wrong here?a

service.php

```
public function getSearch($query)
    {
        return $this->get("/search/search?query={$query}" );
    }
```

I also set a new route for the controller and function

```
Route::post('autocomplete','Controller@autoComplete');
```

controller.php

```
public function autoComplete(Request $request)
{

   $search_result = $request->search_result;

   $service = new service();

   //$search_result = "test"; /*this hard coded value works for passing*/
    $searchResults = $service->getSearch($search_result);

    return $searchResults;
}
```

view.blade.php

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function(){
if($(this).val() === ''){
   return;
}else{

   const searchResult = $(this).val(); 

   $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
            data: {
                'search_result':searchResult
            },
            type: 'POST', 
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

Comment: Put the stack trace in your post.

Comment: You mean from the breakpoint?

Comment: The input event triggers on each keypress so I would expect keying in "Test" to trigger your function four times.  If that's not what you want consider a different event, like change.

Comment: @TomN. paste the error from storage/logs/laravel.log

Comment: @James no that is what I want, I'm trying to build an autocomplete type of functionality. If I type test I get a 4 count but it's all 500 errors

Comment: I would take a look at the ajax response you get back (not just the status code) - you can use your browser developer tools network tab to see that.  You might find a Laravel stack trace that can help you figure out where your php is blowing up.

Comment: @James Do you know where exactly I would see that in the dev tools?

Comment: actually @James I see it in network. It says response content must be a string or object implementing __toString(), "OBject" given

Comment: [see this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770871/the-response-content-must-be-a-string-or-object-implementing-tostring-bool)

Comment: @James so since this doesn't use a model, I should Json encode my $searchResults?

Comment: I would definitely give `return response()->json($searchResults);` a try.

Comment: I just put it in, i'll see how it goes. Thanks!

Comment: @James wow, now I get a 200 on Network, looks like it got it! Thanks for that so much

Answer (score 3):

Add this to your head

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

and pass the token to ajax:

```
$('#productInput').on('input', function(){
if($(this).val() === ''){
   return;
}else{

   const searchResult = $(this).val(); 

   $.ajax({ url: '/account/autocomplete', 
            data: {
                'search_result':searchResult
            },
            "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}", // **** THIS LINE IS ADDED ***** //
            type: 'POST', 
            success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
            }
        });
    }

});
```

I take the ajax part from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32738763/laravel-csrf-token-mismatch-for-ajax-post-request) answer, so thanks to [Deepak saini](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3901691/deepak-saini). If this answer solved your problem, give his answer a plus.

Comment: can i do this without adding to the head? I'm using an extension blade

Comment: Try it without meta but you can put it in your main template anyway.

Comment: I looked at his answer there and used his suggestion so now i have in my Ajax
```data: {
                    "_token": "{{ csrf_token() }}",
                    'search_result':searchResult
                },```
but still 500 errors

Comment: Try again with removing the quotation around search_result:

     search_result:searchResult

Comment: No change there either. Could I need a condition in my controller for it being an AJAX call?

Comment: I don't think so. There's no need to change your method.

Comment: Do you think I need to do anything to my data from the input? It's a string so there shouldn't be a problem inserting that into an endpoint right?