# Javascript problem in Laravel forms with csrf

Tags: laravel

Form in Laravel that is interactive with Javascript - Works fine until I  submit.

I got this error:

> error 419 session expired.

So I add @csrf in my form and Javascript doesn't work.

I want my Javascript form works in Laravel

I try this:

```
<meta name="csrf-token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

And this at the end of body tag(put in script tag):

```
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.open("POST", url , true);
xhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
xhttp.setRequestHeader("X-CSRF-TOKEN", document.head.querySelector("[name=csrf-token]").content );
xhttp.send(params);
```

Also try other things. nothing seems to work. I am really frustrated.

Comment: See [this question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52064145/laravel-ajax-call-from-input-to-controller-function-500-error), it may help.

Comment: I dont use ajax. i use javascript. any idea about fix for javascript

Answer (score 0):

1.add  tag with the token to the blade layout:

```
<meta name="_token" content="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

2.setup ajax requests:

```
$(function() {
  $.ajaxSetup({
    headers: {
      'X-CSRF-Token': $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
    }
  });
});
```

Comment: dont use ajax, only javascript