# Axios Request in a Laravel App returns UnexpectedValueException exception

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, get, axios

I am using **Axios** in a Laravel app for a GET request, however for some reason the request is returning the exception: **UnexpectedValueException** with the message:

> "The Response content must be a string or object implementing
>   __toString(), "boolean" given."

The request is returning this exception, regardless of what I include in the response.

Switching out the **Axios** request for a jQuery request works just fine, so I am assuming it is an issue with the Axios library.

This request returns the exception:

```
axios.get(`/prospect/fetch`);
```

However this jQuery request works just fine:

```
$.get('/prospect/fetch');
```

Laravel fetch function:

```
public function fetch() {
    return response()->json([
        'collection' => Prospect::all()
    ]);
}
```

Route for url:

```
Route::get('/prospect/fetch', 'ProspectController@fetch')->name('admin.dashboard.prospect.fetch');
```

What is wrong with the **Axios** request?

Comment: try to just use like this: `axios.get('/prospect/fetch');` and add then() and catch() function.

Comment: can u install telescope and look at the response body?

Comment: Telescope response says: "Purged By Telescope".

Comment: Are urls the same with both axios and jquery?

Comment: Show your routes, please.

Comment: Same exact routes for both jquery and Axios

Comment: Route for url added to example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should read this answer [object implementing __toString(), "boolean" given.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38770871/the-response-content-must-be-a-string-or-object-implementing-tostring-bool)

Hence, there is some error because of json_encode

you should try `toArray()` method of collection , which can easily convertable to json.

am always return an array in response than a collection object whenever I have to do some ajax calls or send data to javascript.

```
$prospect = Prospect::all()->toArray();
    return response()->json([
            'collection' => $prospect,'status'=>200
        ]);
```

or 
directly Pass

```
return response()->json([
                'collection' => Prospect::all()->toArray(),'status'=>200
            ]);
```

Answer (score 0):

As it says the thing that you are returning must be `string` or an `object` that is implementing `__toString` magic method and you gave `boolean` which is none of those so that is why you are getting that error message.

You can fix the error like this:

```
public function fetch(Request $request) {
    if($request->ajax()) {
        return response()->json(['is_successful' => true]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Good point, however I should point out that the exception is thrown no matter what the function returns. Initially it was returning an eloquent collection, however I simplified it for the example when i wrote the question. I edited the question to show the actual function return.

Comment: @McWayWeb I tested out your fetch method and I see no problem in your fetch method however I think error is from somewhere else.